# httpd 2.4.6 on CentOS 7 - question related to module config in httpd.conf

Tags: centos, configuration, apache-httpd

I am sorry to post this type of question here but due to the great experience and skillsets here, I hope for your understanding.

I am using (unfortunately) httpd package (v 2.4.6).
In various guides, I see that many modules defined in httpd.conf are
loaded as follows (ending with ".c"

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
```

Other modules are to be loaded without that ".c" in the end, such as:

```
<IfModule security2_module>
```

Call me stupid, but I had a hard time to find related, official, documentation about that and so I am just guessing:
Adding ".c" will override the default definitions for that module with the definitions provided. Am I right with that assumption?

If not: can someone please be so kind and point me to the official documentation about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check this [page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#ifmodule):

> The module argument can be either the module identifier or the file name of the module, at the time it was compiled. For example, rewrite_module is the identifier and mod_rewrite.c is the file name. If a module consists of several source files, use the name of the file containing the string STANDARD20_MODULE_STUFF.

In short this means:
The module `mod_rewrite.c` is compiled into `mod_rewrite.so`. The source file `mod_rewrite.c` contains line `module AP_MODULE_DECLARE_DATA rewrite_module;`, which declares a module called `rewrite_module`. So, the module can be referred either as `rewrite_module` or
(module identifier), or `mod_rewrite.c` from which it is compiled.

Directive `LoadModule` tells to load module with identifier `rewrite_module` from compiled object `mod_rewrite.so`. When this is configured, you can either refer to the identifier or the source file name.

Comment: Thank you so much! Just to be very clear (as I am not a native english speaker): Basically it ends up being the same, right?

Comment: Yes, just the way you refer it.